# Dropping common rows in two different dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a beginner using R. I have two different dataframes like the image called df-1 and df-2. I want to combine two dataframes and drop common rows. (Or I want to removal common rows and want to remain unique ID of rows.

Therefore, What I want to make is like df-3.
A `merge` is not appropriate because I don't need common rows.

```
df-1

          ID       NUMBER           FORM     DATE        CD       AD
1        A15      200302033666        1    20031219       3        7
2        B67      200302034466        1    20031204       3        1
3        C15      200302034455        1    20031223       3        1
4        D67      200303918556        1    20030319       3        1
5        E48      200303918575        1    20030304       3        1
6        F80      200303918588        1    20030325       3        1
7        G63      200303918595        1    20030317       3        1



df-2

          ID       NUMBER           FORM    DATE         CD        AD
1        A15      200302033666        1    20031219       3        7
2        K99      200402034466        1    20041204       2        3
3        Z75      200502034455        2    20021222       1        6
4        D67      200303918556        1    20030319       3        1
5        E48      200303918575        1    20030304       3        1
6        F80      200303918588        1    20030325       3        1
7        G63      200303918595        1    20030317       3        1


df-3

          ID       NUMBER           FORM     DATE        CD        AD

1        B67      200302034466        1    20031204       3        1
2        C15      200302034455        1    20031223       3        1
3        K99      200402034466        1    20041204       2        3
4        Z75      200502034455        2    20021222       1        6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rbind` to merge `df1` and `df2` and then selecet `unique` values

`df3 <- unique(rbind(df1,df2))`

Comment: Thank you. Would I ask one more thing? I just compared whether it is unique or not on the ID column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use unique on df3 to keep only unique rows? Or, in one line,

```
df3 <- unique(merge(df1, df2))
```

Also, avoid using brackets when naming variables - df(1) looks like "apply function df to 1"

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you. I want to keep in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly you want a dataframe with records that are present in only one of the original dataframes.
With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df1_anti <- anti_join(df1, df2)
df2_anti <- anti_join(df2, df1)
df3 <- bind_rows(df1_anti, df2_anti)
```

`df1_anti` contains rows present in `df1` but not in `df2`.
`df2_anti` contains rows present in `df2` but not in `df1`.
`df3` is the `UNION` the two dfs.